# Method Overload in Linnworks API

Tags: c#

I'm getting started with the Linnworks API using a [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ka5gU2GbupA) tutorial, however, I'm getting an error on overloading a method GetStockLocation.

In the tutorial, `LinnworksApi.InventoryMethods.GetStockLocations(((LowStockApp.Classes.AppSession)session).LinnworksApiSessionToken,((LowStockApp.Classes.AppSession)session).Server))` is used but currently it looks deprecated so I instead used `LinnworksApi.InventoryController.GetStockLocations(((LowStockApp.Classes.AppSession)session).LinnworksApiSessionToken,((LowStockApp.Classes.AppSession)session).Server))`, it instead gives an error that No overload for method GetStockLocation() takes 2 arguments.

```
public IEnumerable<LinnworksAPI.StockLocation> GetLocations(){
   object session = HttpContext.Current.Items["session"];
   return LinnworksAPI.InventoryController.GetStockLocations(((LowStockApp.Classes.AppSession)session).LinnworksApiSessionToken,((LowStockApp.Classes.AppSession)session).Server);
}
```

Comment: You're trying to call `GetStockLocations`. That's not the same as `GetStockLocation`.